# SED remove the spaces in numbers only not in string

Tags: sed

sample string

> There are 1 123 456 drops of water

Is there a ways to take out the thousand space separator with SED ?
resulting in

> There are 1123456 drops of water

Find the pattern was not difficult 
but I cannot find the how to remove the space

> sed s/[0-9]' '[0-9]/ ??? /

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\) \([0-9]\)/\1\2/g'
```

Comment: @user1152749: first: my pleasure, second: please upvote/accept correct answer if any, third: this is off-topic, I, amongst others, voted to close.

Comment: Works inside windows batch file if you  use double quotes - solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60870977/fuzzy-find-using-exported-google-contacts-remove-newline-inside-double-quotes

Answer (score 0):

This should work too -

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=[0-9])(\s)(?=[0-9])//g'
```

We use a negative look behind and look ahead where we look for numbers in both cases. If we find a space between them, we replace with nothing.

```
[jaypal:~] echo "There are 1 123 456 drops of water" | perl -pe 's/(?<=[0-9])(\s)(?=[0-9])//g'
There are 1123456 drops of water
```